# Accessing plain old ruby object in Spree 1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Spree 1.1 project that's in my rails 3.2 app with a plain ruby object in `app/models/MyObject.rb`

```
class MyObject
  def self.some_method
    # do stuff
  end
end
```

I'm trying to access the model in an override partial

```
Deface::Override.new(:virtual_path => 'spree/products/show',
                     :name => 'unique_name',
                     :insert_after => "[data-hook='product_description']",
                     :partial => 'shared/product_show_stuff')
```

And here's my partial

```
<%= MyObject.some_method %>
```

The error I get is

```
uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::MyObject
```

So I tried the following, hoping the object would be accessible via the global namespace

```
<%= ::MyObject.some_method %>
```

Then I get this error:

```
uninitialized constant MyObject
```

**How can I access my newly created ruby object?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constant should be defined inside a file with a lowercase name:

```
app/models/my_object.rb
```

Not:

```
app/models/MyObject.rb
```

This is so that Rails's autoloading works sufficiently.

Comment: Glad it was something so minor. Thank you Ryan.